# Rotation of a matrix in Scala without using a 2 dimensional Array

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Thanks in advance for the help, I come from a Java background, and new to Scala. for practice. I have been thinking about some of the classic problems from a functional point of view. one such problem is the problem where we have to rotate a matrix by 90 degrees in some direction, here is an example of this problem:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inplace-rotate-square-matrix-by-90-degrees/

the function that I want to implement has this signature:

```
def rotateMatrix[A](mat: Map[(Int,Int),A],n: Int):Map[(Int,Int),A] = {
    mat.map {case (k,v) => k match {
      case (i,j) => (???, ???) -> v
    }}
  }
```

and I feel that there should be some mathematical transformation that I can apply to i and j to transform them to the co-ordinates of the rotated matrix. is this possible?

EDIT: here n is the size of the matrix Eg: for a 3X3 matrix n is 3

Comment: can you please add some code that you have tried?

Comment: well,There is nothing to try I just can't figure out the mathematics involved.
inpired by this page:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330161/how-to-rotate-points-through-90-degree
I tried doing:
```
def rotateMatrix[A](mat: Map[(Int,Int),A],n: Int):Map[(Int,Int),A] = {
    mat.map {case (k,v) => k match {
      case (i,j) => (j, math.abs(n - i)) -> v
    }}
  }
```
but it doesnt work for matrices larger than 2x2

Comment: Actually you are asking others to write code for you in some sort and people are here to help not to spoon feed that’s why I was asking for your effort.

Comment: The question is asking if such a transformation is possible.

Comment: yes it’s possible

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1676441/how-to-rotate-the-positions-of-a-matrix-by-90-degrees

using this function can be implemented as:

```
def rotateMatrix[A](mat: Map[(Int,Int),A],n: Int):Map[(Int,Int),A] = {
    mat map {case (k,v) => k match {
      case (i,j) => (j, n + 1 - i) -> v
    }}
}
```

Edit: based on the input by @jwvh this can be updated to a scala one-liner by:

```
type Matrix[A] = Map[(Int,Int),A]

def rotateMatrix[A](mat: Matrix[A],size: Int):Matrix[A] =
  mat map {case ((i,j),v) => (j, size + 1 - i) -> v}
```

Comment: Which can be simplified to: `mat map {case ((i,j),v) => (j, n + 1 - i) -> v}`

Comment: Thanks that was super helpful